# How to represent dynamic enum-like fields / properties in an Entity Framework 4.1 model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1

I'm trying to whip up a POC of a system which allows you to create and modify enumerations that are eventually used in an application using the front-end. Something like dynamic enums.

For example, in a hypothetical bug tracker application, we can have a `status` enum that could have values of `open`,`accepted` and `closed`. All these enums (and their corresponding values) can be changed in real-time via the UI, so it is possible for an admin to come up with a new `reassigned` value for example (through an Admin page, most probably) somewhere down the application's lifetime. It would also be possible to create new enums as well, which in turn have their own values (for example, a `complexity` enum).

The way I'm currently envisioning it is that I'll have an `Enumeration` class, which has a `1:*` referential with an `EnumerationValue` class.

```
public class Enumeration {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<EnumerationValue> Values { get; set; }
}

public class EnumerationValue {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

That's the easy part. When I get to creating the entity that actually uses these dynamic enums, I hit a snag.

Let's say I'm creating the `BugRecord` entity, which consequently has a `Status` property. Following the logic above, I'd have to write it along the lines of:

```
public class BugRecord {
    public EnumerationValue Status { get; set; }
}
```

But given that I could have lots of different `Enumeration`s (and `EnumerationValue`s), is there a way for me to restrict `BugRecord.Status` values to only `EnumerationValue`s in the status `Enumeration`? If not how would you recommend I tackle a problem of this kind?

Comment: Shouldn't status be an Enumeration and not an EnumerationValue?

Comment: @chemicalNova ~ I don't think so, 'cause the `Enumeration` entities are more of just a grouping? The actual values will be the `EnumerationValue` entities themselves. So if a bug record's status is `active`, then `BugRecord.Status` is analogous to `new EnumerationValue { Name = "Active" }`. Or something like that. What do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a third Entity/JoinTable EnumerationChoice and use it to map the BugRecord to the EnumerationValue

```
public class EnumerationChoice {
    public Enumeration EnumerationCategory { get; set; }
    public EnumerationValue Value { get; set; }
}
```

BugRecord now becomes:

```
public class BugRecord {
    public EnumerationChoice BugType { get; set; }
    public EnumerationChoice Status { get; set; }
}
```

The data would now look like:

```
BugRecord:
    EnumerationChoice:
        -BugType
        -BugTypeValue1
    EnumerationChoice:
        -Status
        -Open
```

This way, when you try to populate the EnumerationChoice, you can reference the EnumerationCategory to get the valid EnumerationValues assigned to it.